# Get count of multiple condition

Tags: php, mysql

My question is I want to get the count of three condition in a single query. I know I can do this with running multiple query but the problem is all I need it in one query

My query what I have tried is

```
SELECT COUNT( IF( da <3, da, 0 ) ) AS da1, 
       COUNT( IF( da <2, da, 0 ) ) AS da2, 
       COUNT( IF( da <1, da, 0 ) ) AS da3
FROM tv
```

And its result is

```
4 4 4
```

But the expected result is

```
2 1 0
```

The data present inside table for `da` column is

```
3 2 1 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM( IF( rr <3, 1, 0 ) ) AS da1, 
       SUM( IF( rr <2, 1, 0 ) ) AS da2, 
       SUM( IF( rr <1, 1, 0 ) ) AS da3
FROM tv;
```

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT()` needs to be used with `GROUP BY` - i think that may be your problem, try grouping by `da`.

Comment: I tried with `group by` but it gives me wrong output. 3 X 3 matrix output.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution for my question but **PSR's** solution is also right

```
SELECT * 
FROM (

    SELECT COUNT( da ) AS da1
    FROM tv
    WHERE da <3
    ) AS da1, (

    SELECT COUNT( da ) AS da2
    FROM tv
    WHERE da <2
    ) AS da2, (

    SELECT COUNT( da ) AS da3
    FROM tv
    WHERE da <1
    ) AS da3
```

Comment: that's not one query anymore though.

Comment: @MarshallHouse its subquery.